# What do the @Stable and @Immutable annotations mean in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

While studying through the Jetpack Compose sample project, I saw `@Stable` and `@Immutable` annotations. I've been looking through the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lifecycle#skipping) and [GitHub](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/docs/compose-api-guidelines.md#stable-types) about those annotations, but I don't understand.

From what I understand, if use `@Immutable`, even if the state is changed, recomposition should not occur. However, as a result of the test, recomposition proceeds.

What exactly do `@Stable` and `@Immutable` annotations do in Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**The definition**

`@Immutable` is an annotation to tell Compose compiler that this object is immutable for optimization, so without using it, there will be unnecessary re-composition that might get triggered.

`@Stable` is another annotation to tell the Compose compiler that this object might change, but when it changes, Compose runtime will be notified.

It might not make sense if you read up to here. So more explanation...

---

**The Compose metrics report**

When you generate the compose metrics report (https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/08c6116/compose/compiler/design/compiler-metrics.md), it will mark things as `stable` or `unstable`, for `unstable` objects, Compose compiler cannot tell if the object is modified, so it has to trigger recomposition regardlessly. Here's two snippets of how the report looks like:

```
restartable skippable scheme("[androidx.compose.ui.UiComposable]") fun SomeClass1(
  stable modifier: Modifier? = @static Companion
)

restartable scheme("[androidx.compose.ui.UiComposable]") fun SomeClass2(
  stable modifier: Modifier? = @static Companion
  stable title: String
  unstable list: List<User>
  stable onClicked: Function1<User>, Unit>
)
```

**skippable is desired!**

In the case of `SomeClass1`, it is marked as `skippable`, because all of it's parameters are marked `stable`. For `SomeClass2`, it doesn't get marked as `skippable`, because it has a property `list` that is `unstable`.

When it's marked as `skippable`, it is a good thing, because Compose compiler can skip recomposition whenever possible and it's more optimized.

**when will it fail to be marked as skippable?**

Usually compose compiler is smart enough to deduce what is `stable` and what is `unstable`. In the cases where compose compiler cannot tell the stability are mutable objects, e.g. a class that contains `var` properties.

```
class SomeViewState {
  var isLoading: Boolean
}
```

Another case where it will fail to decide the stability would be for classes like `Collection`, such as `List`, because even the interface is `List` which looks immutable, it can actually be a mutable list. Example:

```
data class SomeViewState {
    val list: List<String>
}
@Composable
fun ShowSomething(data: SomeViewState) {
}
```

Even though the Composable above accepts `SomeViewState` where all it's property is `val`, it is still `unstable`. You might wonder why? That's because on the use side, you can actually use it with a `MutableList`, like this:

```
ShowSomething(SomeViewState(mutableListOf()))
```

For this reason, the compiler will have to mark this as `unstable`.

So in cases like this, what we want to achieve is to make them `stable` again, so they are optimized.

---

**@Stable and @Immutable**

There are 2 ways to make it `stable` again, which are using `@Stable` and `@Immutable`.

Using `@Stable`, as mentioned above, it means that the value can be changed, but when it does change, we have to notify Compose compiler. The way to do it is through using `mutableStateOf()`:

```
@Stable
class SomeViewState {
  var isLoading by mutableStateOf(false)
}
```

Using `@Immutable`, it means that you will always make a new copy of the data when you pass into the Composable, in other wards, you make a promise that your data is immutable. From the example above:

```
@Immutable
data class SomeViewState {
    val list: List<String>
}
@Composable
fun ShowSomething(data: SomeViewState) {
}
```

After annotating with `@Immutable`, on your use side, you should make sure to  make a new list instead of mutating your list directly.

Example DO:

```
class ViewModel {
    val state: SomeViewState = SomeViewState(listOf())
    fun removeLastItem() {
        val newList = state.list.toMutableList().apply {
                removeLast()
            }
        state = state.copy(
            list = newList
        )
    }
}
```

Example DON'T:

```
class ViewModel {
    val state: SomeViewState = SomeViewState(mutableListOf())
    fun removeLastItem() {
        state.list.removeLast() // <=== you violate your promise of @Immutable!
    }
}
```

---

For deeper understanding, you can read this links:

- https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/jetpack-compose-stability-explained-79c10db270c8
- https://chris.banes.dev/composable-metrics/

Comment: This is a perfect explanation.

Comment: A way better (or actual deeper) explanation than the accepted answer. Nice job! Thank you .

Comment: In the `@Immutable SomeViewState` sample you can also use Kotlin's official [Immutable Collections Library](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable) (alpha) `PersistentList` implementation, e.g. `val list: PersistentList<String> = persistentListOf()`. That way you wouldn't need to provide an own list modification implementation in your `ViewModel` as `PersistentList` takes care of the copying (and can even share the underlying data structure for added efficiency).

Answer (score 44):

The compiler treats both identically but

- using `@Immutable` is a promise that the value will never change.
- using `@Stable` is a promise that the value is observable and if it does change listeners are notified.

Comment: what's the advantage of annotating a class with these?

Comment: @JimOvejera - They let the compose compiler do some optimizations, resulting in smaller and faster recomposition logic.

Comment: can you give us some custom implementation of @Stable ? (other than compose builtins like Color etc)

Comment: When using @Stable, it's necessary to use mutableStateOf?

Comment: @TedHopp "some optimizations" like what? Can you add reference?

Comment: @Farid - Composition skips composables when state hasn't changed. Sometimes it can infer that things haven't changed on its own. The annotations `@Immutable` and `@Stable` help it do so for objects that might otherwise trigger recomposition. See, for instance, https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/jetpack-compose-stability-explained-79c10db270c8 or https://www.jetpackcompose.app/articles/how-can-I-debug-recompositions-in-jetpack-compose.

Comment: @TedHopp Thank you, now that makes total sense

Comment: Why, for example, is `Color` marked as `@Stable` instead of `@Immutable`?